# While running 'pod setup' in terminal, it fails with below error -

Tags: cocoapods

While running 'pod setup' in terminal, it fails with below error:

> error: RPC failed; curl 56 SSLRead() return error -36
>   fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
>   fatal: early EOF fatal: index-pack failed

Answer (score 0):

Increase the http buffer 
git config http.postBuffer 524288000

and still gettin the issue please 
Please open the terminal and execute this 
`git config --global user.email "youremail@xxx.xxx"`
then try `pod setup`